# Disable cell depending on value of Column A, updating on change of cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that in column A, I have a validation of "AMT" or "Single". I am trying to make it so that depending on which on is selected, it disables a cell in a different column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"

    If Range("A1").Value = "AMT" Then
        Range("D1").Locked = True
        Range("M1").Locked = False
    End If

    If Range("A1").Value = "Single" Then
        Range("D1").Locked = False
        Range("M1").Locked = True
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"

End Sub
```

This code doesn't seem to be working. The code above locks the entire sheet when I change a value in A1, not just the columns I am looking to disable.

Furthermore I will have data for 1000 rows so I need this to loop through all rows that contains "AMT" or "Single" in column A and therefor will need to run this code every time the user changes a value in column A.

Comment: If you want to check only cell `A1` then the above code should work as intended (if that sub is placed on the corresponding sheet). If you want to check **all** values in column `A` (even though only one cell might have been changed) then you'll have to adjust your code with something like `If Target.Column = 1 Then` and then `Select Case Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value2`. Note, that `Target` might not be a single cell but might refer to a range of cells. So, you might want to iterate through them using `For Each cell in Target`.

Comment: The Code above locks the entire sheet. no just the columns I'm looking to disable. The worksheet also locks if i enter a value is `B1`. I am just trying to get it so that if I enter `AMT` in `A1` then `D1` is locked and if I enter `Single` into `A1` then `M1` is locked instead

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by the ActiveSheet.Protect command always protecting the entire worksheet, except for unlocked cells. In your IF statements you're telling it only to unlock M1, but lock all the rest.

One solution to the problem would be to unlock the entire worksheet and lock only the cell you want to lock, something like this:

```
If Range("A1").Value = "AMT" Then
       Range("A1:Z500").Locked = False ´
       Range("D1").Locked = True 
End If
```

Hope this helps.